# On tkinter: scrolling multiple widgets simultaneously in different frames

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda

Below is an example on how to scroll two canvasses in two separate frames simultaneously. The trick is on how to pass on `*args` from the bindings to function `onscroll` for scrolling and `onresize` for changing the dimensions of the rectangle using `lambda` in the commands: `Scrollbar(frame3, orient='vertical', command=lambda *args: onscroll('axis', *args))` and `Button(frame3, text='reduce ', command=lambda *args: onresize(False, *args))`.

Is this the best way to handle this?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Frame, Canvas, Scrollbar, Button

global size_x, size_y, canvas1, canvas2, block1, block2
size_x = size_y = 150
block1 = block2 = ''


def onscroll(axis, *args):
    global canvas1, canvas2
    print(f'axis: {axis} and args are {[*args]}                           ',
          end='\r')
    if axis == 'x-axis':
        canvas1.xview(*args)
        canvas2.xview(*args)
    elif axis == 'y-axis':
        canvas1.yview(*args)
        canvas2.yview(*args)

    else:
        assert False, f"axis {axis} is incorrect, use 'x-axis' or 'y-axis'"


def onresize(enlarge, *args):
    global size_x, size_y
    print(f'enlarge: {enlarge} and args are {[*args]}                    ',
          end='\r')
    if enlarge:
        size_x *= 1.1
        size_y *= 1.1
    else:
        size_x /= 1.1
        size_y /= 1.1


def main():
    global canvas1, canvas2, block1, block2
    root = tk.Tk()
    frame1 = Frame(root, bg='grey')
    frame1.grid(row=0, column=0)
    frame2 = Frame(root, bg='grey')
    frame2.grid(row=0, column=1)
    frame3 = Frame(root, bg='grey')
    frame3.grid(row=0, column=2)

    yscrollbar = Scrollbar(frame3, orient='vertical',
                           command=lambda *args: onscroll('y-axis', *args))
    yscrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y', expand='yes')
    xscrollbar = Scrollbar(frame3, orient='horizontal',
                           command=lambda *args: onscroll('x-axis', *args))
    xscrollbar.pack(side='bottom', fill='x', expand='yes')

    reduce_button = Button(frame3, text='reduce ',
                           command=lambda *args: onresize(False, *args))
    reduce_button.pack(side='right', anchor='ne')
    enlarge_button = Button(frame3, text='enlarge',
                            command=lambda *args: onresize(True, *args))
    enlarge_button.pack(side='right', anchor='ne')

    canvas1 = Canvas(frame1, width=200, height=200, bg="blue",
                     scrollregion=(0, 0, 500, 500),
                     yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set,
                     xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set)
    canvas1.pack(side='right')
    canvas2 = Canvas(frame2, width=200, height=200, bg="yellow",
                     scrollregion=(0, 0, 500, 500),
                     yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set,
                     xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set)
    canvas2.pack()

    canvas3 = Canvas(frame3, width=200, height=200, bg='pink')
    canvas3.pack()

    while True:
        canvas1.delete(block1)
        canvas2.delete(block2)
        block1 = canvas1.create_rectangle(100, 100, size_x, size_y,
                                          fill='orange')
        block2 = canvas2.create_rectangle(100, 100, size_x, size_y,
                                          fill='blue')
        root.update()

    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 3):

### Remove unnecessary imports

You're importing parts of tkinter twice, Remove this line:

```
from tkinter import Frame, Canvas, Scrollbar, Button
```

Then, whenever you need to use `Frame`, `Canvas`, etc, use `tk.Frame`, `tk.Canvas`, etc.

### Don't create your own event loop

You have code that looks like this:

```
while True:
    <some code>
    root.update()
```

Instead, call `mainloop` once, move `<some code>` into a function, and call it with `after` if you need it to run in a loop.

```
def redraw():
    <some code>
    root.after(50, redraw)
root.mainloop()
```

### Don't continually delete and recreate items on a canvas

You're continually deleting and recreating identical items on a canvas. This is inefficient and will eventually call tkinter to crash. The canvas widget does not re-use canvas ids, so each time you create a new object you get a new id. There is a limited number of ids that tkinter can manage.

Instead, create the items once, and then if you need to change them, change the existing items

```
def draw():
    global block1, block2
    block1 = canvas1.create_rectangle(100, 100, size_x, size_y,
                                      fill='orange')
    block2 = canvas2.create_rectangle(100, 100, size_x, size_y,
                                      fill='blue')

def redraw():
    global block1, block2
    canvas1.itemconfigure(block1, ...)
    canvas2.itemconfigure(block2, ...)
```

### Group your layout code together

Intermixing widget creation and widget layout makes the code hard to read.

Consider this:

```
frame1 = Frame(root, bg='grey')
frame1.grid(row=0, column=0)
frame2 = Frame(root, bg='grey')
frame2.grid(row=0, column=1)
frame3 = Frame(root, bg='grey')
frame3.grid(row=0, column=2)
```

I recommend splitting this into two blocks:

```
frame1 = Frame(root, bg='grey')
frame2 = Frame(root, bg='grey')
frame3 = Frame(root, bg='grey')

frame1.grid(row=0, column=0)
frame2.grid(row=0, column=1)
frame3.grid(row=0, column=2)
```

I think this makes the code much easier to read because I can see at a glance that you're creating three frames, and that each frame is going into a separate column. In the original code it's not nearly as easy to see this without closely reading the code.

### Use separate functions for scrolling in x and y direction

Your use of an argument to specify x-axis or y-axis makes the code a little bit harder to understand. Instead, I recommend using two separate functions.

For example:

```
def scroll_x(*args):
    global canvas1, canvas2
    canvas1.xview(*args)
    canvas2.xview(*args)

def scroll_y(*args):
    global canvas1, canvas2
    canvas1.yview(*args)
    canvas2.yview(*args)
...
yscrollbar = Scrollbar(frame3, orient='vertical', command=scroll_y)
xscrollbar = Scrollbar(frame3, orient='horizontal', command=scroll_x)
```

Notice how it makes the code much easier to read, since we can replace the complicated lambda with a much simpler command.

Comment: Thanks for the very useful tips. Three questions:  1) as I am changing the dimensions of the rectangle (100, 100, size_x, size_y) I am not sure how to implement this with itemconfigure as it seems only the options can be used as input and not the positional paramters? 2) am I correct that redraw is a recursive function, i.e. the function calls itself? 3) what is a graceful way to exit the redraw function, do I use root.destroy on some condition?